# Toggle compiled code (instead of mapped source) while debugging JavaScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When debugging JavaScript in VS Code, source maps are not always perfect for various reasons (e.g. Babel can obfuscate symbol names, or complex transpiled constructs don't map directly to source). While generally source maps work excellently in VS Code as of late, there are still times when you'd like to look at the compiled JavaScript.

Is there any way to toggle to the actual executing code while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution, but right now you can also add debug pointer in the compiled js files.

Those pointer will map directly to the source even if the opposite doesn't work!